# slow boot after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: boot, networking, systemd

After update from 16.04 to 18.04 the boot-process feels slow:

```
systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 34.455s (kernel) + 23.569s (userspace) = 58.025s
graphical.target reached after 17.137s in userspace

systemd-analyze blame
         22.057s usb_modeswitch@1-2.service
         10.830s networking.service
          5.162s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          1.565s vmware.service
          1.344s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          1.231s tor@default.service
           895ms fwupd.service
           685ms ufw.service
           670ms dev-mapper-rootvg\x2dlv_root.device
           659ms dev-mapper-rootvg\x2dlv_usr.device
           628ms mpd.service
           607ms keyboard-setup.service
           537ms postfix@-.service
           501ms vmware-workstation-server.service
           444ms vmware-USBArbitrator.service
           394ms networkd-dispatcher.service
           388ms ModemManager.service
           379ms udisks2.service
           330ms NetworkManager.service
           308ms tlp.service
           299ms accounts-daemon.service
           256ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           245ms auditd.service
           240ms grub-common.service
           235ms systemd-logind.service
           234ms snapd.service
           227ms apport.service
           225ms virtualbox.service
           207ms apache2.service
           205ms avahi-daemon.service
           176ms gpu-manager.service
           175ms sysstat.service
           174ms alsa-restore.service
           168ms pppd-dns.service
           159ms rsyslog.service
           152ms lvm2-pvscan@8:4.service
           145ms user@127.service
           134ms upower.service
           132ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           130ms apparmor.service
           125ms systemd-resolved.service
           115ms snap-core-4571.mount
           115ms teamviewerd.service
            85ms snap-keepassxc-37.mount
            81ms snap-core-4486.mount
```

I'm not sure how to improve usb_modeswitch and networking.service. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: usb_modeswitch cam from an old USB-3G-Modem. After purging usb-modeswitch packets the overall time to start the OS didn't change that much. Seems, that the upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 didn't work to 100%. According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_16.04_LTS I will wait until the official update is pronounced. A dd if=sda3.iso bs=4M of=/dev/sda3 fixed it. I'm back on 16.04.